# Can update Windows 10 lead to dual-boot with Ubuntu issues in a GPT hard disk?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, windows-update, gpt

I read this [article](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/risks-dual-booting-windows-linux-operating-systems/) before installing Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 and according to the ninth case in the article, update Windows can lead to Master Boot Record being rewritten and leaving with a missing Linux partition. However, I could successfully install Ubuntu alongside Windows without any issues and everything works fine. The hard disk Windows and Ubuntu is installed on is of the GPT partition style, my computer supports UEFI, the secure boot feature is turned on and the primary operating system is Windows.

So, can still update Windows 10 lead to dual-boot with Ubuntu issues? If so, what issues and how can I fix them?

Comment: In my experience: Yes it can. Probably not with the "small" normal windows updates, but do you remember the windows update of april 2020? Such big upgrades can, and probably will break at least you boot order. I once had the case that windows simply straight up wiped my EFI partition an replaced it with its own. BUT: You main linux partition will be left untouched. So i suggest backing up your EFI partition once in a while (you can do that from within ubuntu and copy it to a usb stick).

Take all this with a grain of salt, as I really am not the biggest Windows supporter.

Comment: @Malik "I once had the case that windows simply straight up wiped my EFI partition an replaced it with its own", really? Are you sure it didn't simply changed the boot order to itself? This claim is dubious, nobody else ever reported such issue in UEFI/GPT.

Comment: Yes, very sure, but the laptop that it happend on was a special case anyway. This is from quite a distant memory (about 5-6 years), so no guarantees: The chip set of this model had some "auto repair" function, for Windows EFI. If I changed the boot order, as soon as windows would boot, it would reorder, so that windows was back on top. I even tinkered with moveing some files out of the Windows EFI dir, but as soon as I started Windows, it magically repaired the boot manager, and Windows would be on top once again.

Comment: I don't quite remember my solution anymore, but it was something along the lines of actually breaking the Windows Bootmanager, and having GRUB repair it on the fly, when i wanted to boot into Windows. The Laptop was some HP. No clue about the modelnumber anymore